# In Hashicorp Vault, how can I prevent "userpass" users from changing each others policies and passwords?

Tags: hashicorp-vault

After creating my first user, I noticed that I'm able to change my own policies:

```
$ vault write auth/userpass/users/mconigliaro policies=root
Success! Data written to: auth/userpass/users/mconigliaro
```

Even worse than that, it looks like users can change each other's passwords:

```
$ vault write auth/userpass/users/mconigliaro2 password=foobar
Success! Data written to: auth/userpass/users/mconigliaro2
```

Looking at the [policy documentation](https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/concepts/policies.html), I think I should be able to create a policy that looks something like this:

```
path "auth/userpass/users/${user}" {
  capabilities = ["update"]
  allowed_parameters = {
    "password" = []
  } 
}
```

But unfortunately, this depends on the concept of a policy variable (e.g. `${user}`) that Vault doesn't seem to have. Do I have to create individual policies for each user with hardcoded paths, or is there some easier way that I'm missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What user/token are you currently authenticated with Vault as? I'm guessing root? So yes, you'll be able to do anything. You, and certainly your users, wouldn't normally have root privileges.

Log in as one of the users you've created, and you'll find you can't perform the actions you describe.

Comment: Oops, I think you're right. I must have been using the root token inadvertently. Thanks!